# Handling Executors in RxKotlin

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I will be using thread executors to do some background work with rxkotlin, I made threadpool size fixed to 3, but my problem is during my background operation it using only one thread out of 3, which slows down my background operation

Executor class

```
 class ThreadExe : Executor{

     companion object {
        private const val THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 3
    }

    private val executor: Executor = 
       Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE)

    override fun execute(runnable: Runnable) {
          executor.execute(runnable)
    }

}
```

The above is my executor class responsible for creating thread.
I will be calling my background task like below

```
 getSomeDataFromNetworkProcessWithDB()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(ThreadExe()))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe()
```

```
fun getSomeDataFromNetworkProcessWithDB() {
    Observable.fromIteratable(someDataList())
            .flatMap {
                getSomeNetworkData()
            }
            .flatMap {
                doSomeDbOperation()
            }
}
```

my problem with the above code is all these network and db operation is working sequentially with the same thread, since we have give the threadpool of size 3 it must send the 3 network request parallely, but the request is going sequentially
Can anyone help me out this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want individual operation to run on different thread try this:

```
    getSomeDataFromNetworkProcessWithDB(Schedulers.from(ThreadExe()))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe()
```

```
fun getSomeDataFromNetworkProcessWithDB(scheduler: Scheduler): Observable<Data> {
    return Observable.fromIterable(someDataList())
            .flatMap {
                getSomeNetworkData().subscribeOn(scheduler)
            }
            .flatMap {
                doSomeDbOperation().subscribeOn(scheduler)
            }
            .subscribeOn(scheduler) // optional, if you want fromIterable(), someDataList() to run on this scheduler.
}
```